# Custom gridline on Excel chart

Tags: excel, charts

Excel 2016 VBA

I have an Excel chart of type xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers. Lets say I set the X axis gridlines to range from 40 to 200:

```
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 40
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 200
```

This gives major gridlines at 40, 60 80, 100, 120, 140, 160, 180 and 200. 
What I need here is to have an additional gridline on the X-axis with value 90, preferably a bit thicker than the original ones.
How do I accomplish that with VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A line connects two points, right? So add a line using two points.

**Manual Approach**

Set up a range with Xmin and Xmax in one column, and 90 in the two cells next to these.Use this formula to calculate the values in a column in the sheet. Then plot this column in your chart.

Copy this range, select the chart, and use Paste Special from the dropdown on the Paste button on the Home tab of the ribbon. Add the data as a new series, with categories (X values) in the first column. Format the line as desired, and you'll probably have to reset the X axis scale.

**VBA Approach**

This code adds a horizontal line at Y=90, and makes it the same color as the gridlines but twice the line width.

```
With ActiveChart
  With .Axes(xlCategory)
    Dim Xmin As Double, xMax As Double
    Xmin = .MinimumScale
    xMax = .MaximumScale
    .MinimumScaleIsAuto = False
    .MaximumScaleIsAuto = False
  End With
  Dim srs As Series
  Set srs = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
  With srs
    .Values = Array(90, 90)
    .XValues = Array(Xmin, xMax)
    .PlotOrder = 1
  End With
  With .Axes(xlValue)
    .MinimumScale = 40
    .MaximumScale = 200
    srs.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = .MajorGridlines.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB
    srs.Format.Line.Weight = 2 * .MajorGridlines.Format.Line.Weight
  End With
End With
```

Comment: "Copy this range, select the chart, and use Paste Special from the dropdown ..."



  Where in my question did I omit VBA?

Comment: Watch your snark. Did you mean where did you _say to_ omit VBA? If you can do it manually, you can do it with VBA.

Comment: No, I meant what I wrote. Thanks for the VBA part.